# Optimize 4D Numpy array construction

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, slice

I have a 4D array `data` of shape (50,8,2048,256) which are 50 groups containing 8  2048x256 pixel images. `times` is an array of shape (50,8) giving the time that each image was taken.

I calculate a 1st order polynomial fit at each pixel for all images in each group, giving me an array of shape (50,2048,256,2). This is essentially a vector plot for each of the 50 groups. The code I use to store the polynomials is:

```
fits = np.ones((50,2048,256,2))
times = times.reshape(50,8,1).repeat(2048,2).reshape(50,8,2048,1).repeat(256,3)
for group in range(50):    
    for xpos in range(2048):
        for ypos in range(256):
            px_data = data[:,:,ypos,xpos]
            fits[group,ypos,xpos,:] = np.polyfit(times[group,:,ypos,xpos],data[group,:,ypos,xpos],1)
```

Now the challenge is that I want to generate an array `new_data` of shape (50,12,2048,256) where I use the polynomial coefficients from `fits` and the times from `new_time` to generate 50 groups of 12 images.

I figure I can use something like `np.polyval(fits, new_time)` to generate the images but I'm very confused with how to phrase it. It should be something like:

```
new_data = np.ones((50,12,2048,256))
for i,(times,fit) in enumerate(zip(new_times,fits)):
    new_data[i] = np.polyval(fit,times)
```

But I'm getting broadcasting errors. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
Ok, so I changed the code a bit so that it does work and do exactly what I want, but it is terribly slow with all these loops (~1 minute per group meaning this would take me almost an hour to run!). Can anyone suggest a way to optimize this to speed it up?

```
# Generate the polynomials for each pixel in each group
fits = np.ones((50,2048,256,2))
times = np.arange(0,50*8*grptme,grptme).reshape(50,8)
times = times.reshape(50,8,1).repeat(2048,2).reshape(50,8,2048,1).repeat(256,3)
for group in range(50):
    for xpos in range(2048):
        for ypos in range(256):
            fits[group,xpos,ypos] = np.polyfit(times[group,:,xpos,ypos],data[group,:,xpos,ypos],1)

# Create new array of 12 images per group using the polynomials for each pixel
new_data = np.ones((50,12,2048,256))
times = np.arange(0,50*12*grptme,grptme).reshape(50,12)
times = times.reshape(50,12,1).repeat(2048,2).reshape(50,12,2048,1).repeat(256,3)
for group in range(50):
    for img in range(12):
        for xpos in range(2048):
            for ypos in range(256):
                new_data[group,img,xpos,ypos] = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(times[group,img,xpos,ypos],fits[group,xpos,ypos])
```

Comment: Looks like fit and times are both going to be multi-dimensionsal arrays, but the documentation of `numpy.polyval` indicates it wants 1D arrays.  You might look into `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval` (documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval))

Comment: @Ajean Yes that looks like the right function to use, thanks! But any advice on how to apply it to the data set? I want to generate 12 images in each group using the group's polynomial coefficients, for an array of shape (50,12,2048,256).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the speed I see a lot of loops which is what should and often can be avoided due to the beauty of numpy. If I understand your problem fully you want to fit a first order polynom on 50 groups of 8 data points 2048 * 256 times. So for the fit the shape of your image does not play a role. So my suggestion is to flatten your images because with `np.polyfit` you can fit for a range of x-values several sets of y-values at the same time

From the doc string

```
x : array_like, shape (M,)
    x-coordinates of the M sample points ``(x[i], y[i])``.
y : array_like, shape (M,) or (M, K)
    y-coordinates of the sample points. Several data sets of sample
    points sharing the same x-coordinates can be fitted at once by
    passing in a 2D-array that contains one dataset per column.
```

So I would go for

```
# Generate the polynomials for each pixel in each group
fits = np.ones((50,2048*256,2))
times = np.arange(0,50*8*grptme,grptme).reshape(50,8)
data_fit = data.reshape((50,8,2048*256))
for group in range(50):
    fits[group] = np.polyfit(times[group],data_fit[group],1).T
fits_original_shape = fits.reshape((50,2048,256,2))
```

The transposing is necessary since you want to have the parameters in the last index, but `np.polyfit` has them first and then the different data sets

And then to evaluate it it is basically the same trick again:

```
# Create new array of 12 images per group using the polynomials for each pixel
new_data = np.zeros((50,12,2048*256))
times = np.arange(0,50*12*grptme,grptme).reshape(50,12)
#times = times.reshape(50,12,1).repeat(2048,2).reshape(50,12,2048,1).repeat(256,3)
for group in range(50):
    new_data[group] = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(times[group],fits[group].T).T
new_data_original_shape = new_data.reshape((50,12,2048,256))
```

The two transposes are again needed due to the ordering of the parameters vs. the different data sets so that matches with the shapes of your arrays.

Probably one could also avoid with some advanced numpy magic the loop over the groups, but with this the code runs much faster already.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Just refactored it and calculate that this is about 4% faster than my attempt. Faster is better but even faster would be even better!